# Using Laplace transformation method find the solution to the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, differential

$$x''+x=e^{-λt}\cos(μt),~~x(0)=A, x'(0)=B$$
λ, μ, A, B, all are constants. There are so many unknown constants in this problem. I am facing difficulty in solving this. Using Laplace transformation,
$$X(s)=\frac{(s+λ)}{((s+λ)^2+μ^2)(s^2+1)}+\frac{(As+B)}{(s^2+1)}$$
I tried to solve this using partial fraction but failed.
$$\frac{(s+λ)}{((s+λ)^2+μ^2)(s^2+1)}=\frac{(Cs+D)}{((s+λ)^2+μ^2)}+\frac{(Es+F)}{(s^2+1)}$$
$$(s+λ)=(Cs+D)(s^2+1)+(Es+F)((s+λ)^2+μ^2)$$
By equating the coefficients i got,
$$C+E=0~~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~(i)$$
$$D+Eλ+F=0~~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~(ii)$$
$$C+E(λ^2+μ^2)+Fλ=1~~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~(iii)$$
$$D+F(λ^2+μ^2)=λ~~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~.~(iv)$$

Any ideas or suggestions to find out the solution to the differential equation, I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X(s)=\frac{(s+λ)}{((1+λ)^2+μ)(s^2+1)}+\frac{(As+B)}{(s^2+1)}$$
The last fraction is easy to decompose and take inverse Laplace transform. It's simply the solution to the homogeneous differential equation ($x''+x=0$) :
$$\mathcal L^{-1}\left (\frac{As+B}{s^2+1} \right )=A \cos t + B\sin t$$

The first fraction should give you the particular solution to the inhomogeneous differential equation.

It seems to me you made a little mistake. You should have at the denominator $(s+\lambda )^2+\mu^2$.

You have to discuss. There is a special case where $\lambda =0$ and $\mu =1$ in this case the fraction decomposition is different. You will have to decompose:
$$G(s)=\dfrac {s}{(s^2+1)^2}$$
$$\implies g(t)=\dfrac 12 t \sin t$$

Comment: "It seems to me you made a little mistake. You should have at the denominator (s−λ)2+1 not s2+1"-- Yeah, typing mistake, edited.

Comment: No problem @MirSazzatHossain ........

Comment: I almost got the answer. Can you please help me to break down the first part into partial fractions? @Aryadeva

Comment: For the first fraction I added some lines in my answer. You have to treat two different cases @MirSazzatHossain